# Date difference not matching

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query which gives the below output. The '06/01/20' is some corrupted data I need to deal with. Converting it to 'DD/MM/YY' is not an option, I just would like to understand what's happening here.

```
WITH aux (
    d1,
    d2
) AS (
    SELECT
        '06/01/20',
        '15/01/2021'
    FROM
        dual
)
SELECT
    nvl(to_date(d2, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), sysdate) - to_date(d1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') diff
FROM
    aux;
```

Output:

```
DIFF
----
730862
```

However, if I do the below, the results do not match with what I would expect, the difference between those dates would be

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE('06/01/20', 'DD/MM/YYYY') d1,
    TO_DATE('15/01/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') d2
FROM
    dual
```

Output:

```
       D1          D2
---------------------
06-JAN-20   15-JAN-21
```

--

```
SELECT
    DATE '2021-01-15' - DATE '2020-01-06' d
FROM
    dual
```

Output:

```
D
-
9
```

Comment: You want `RR` for two digit years.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand that. Could you please provide an example? Also, I would like to understand what's happening in my code, not just how to fix it.

Comment: `to_date('06/01/20', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` produces `0020-01-06`, not `2020-01-06`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález indeed, that was what I was looking for. Feel free to post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you set a default date format that allows to see full dates. Many Oracle clients have such settings and you can also change it for current session:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD';
```

When you do so you'll realise that `TO_DATE('06/01/20', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` produces `0020-01-06` rather than `2020-01-06`.

*An average year has 365.25 days and 730862 / 365,25 equals 2001 ;-)*

Comment: Gracias!! :) :)